# how to override a css class without affecting other classes with the same name

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, overriding

I have many widgets that are combined in a single page, however i need to override a `container` class for a certain widget, but what is happening is that all widgets having a class with the same name are affected. below is screenshot from the inspect element

[image]

the selected row with `class=container` is the widget that i want to edit.

Many thanks

Comment: Then you need to select it another way, selecting by index would be the easiest way

Comment: you can select the specific container with nth-child and style it accordingly

Comment: Or add an ID to the element that you want to target

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can approach this. One, you can create an id for that HTML tag that you want add'l/different style and create a `#<id_name>` in your css to handle that style or add another classname in front of `container` for the one you want to style. Or you can use CSS specificity for the nth child render this add'l style.

#### Approach 1)

**HTML**

```
<tagname id="other_css" class="container" ...>
```

**CSS**

```
#other_css {
  // css stuff
}
```

#### Approach 2

**HTML**

```
<tagname class="container other_css" ...>
```

**CSS**

```
.other_css {
  ...
}

.container {
  ....
}
```

#### Approach 3

**HTML**

```
<wrapper>
  <tagname class="container ...>
  <tagname class="container ...>
  <tagname class="container ...> <- the one you care about 
</wrapper>
```

**CSS**

```
wrapper:nth-child(3) {
  ...
}
```

Resources:
- https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#specificity

Comment: i am trying the third approach which is the only choice i have as i can't add class or id to the widget. the problem is that the wrapper is a div, and there are two divs inside the first div, and the containers are inside the second div

`<div>
<div>..</div>
<div>..</div>
<div>
<div class ='container'>..</div>
<div class ='container'>..</div>
<div class ='container'>..</div>
<div class ='container'>..</div>
</div>
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want to have a different styling for one of the elements with the class `container`. A good practice would be to create another class with the special styling: `container new-class`

Answer (score 0):

Just add another class beside `container` class and define/write your desired css code inside the new class.

Comment: no, the classes are generated dynamically, i don't want to add any classes or ids to the widgets

Answer (score 0):

Dear I think you want to override the default class name `container` of bootstrap which is a bad approach and make hurdles in future for you.

So better to use some `div` with class name inside `container` and do what ever you want to...

An if you are bound to not update html then try to use `.container:nth-child(5)` where (5) is the number on which that class is.